# Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Tags: arrays, swift

In my code below, the contents of `winRankArray` are all string objects. The issue I'm having is that setting the `didWinRank` variable at the end gives me the following error:

> Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

I've tried removing `?`so that setting card ranks looks like `var cardRank1 = deckDictionary[cardKey1].first`, but that gives me an error stating

> Value of optional type 'Array?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

How can I set the variables so that the resulting `winRankArray` doesn't have this problem?

```
        var cardKey1 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank1 = deckDictionary[cardKey1]?.first

        var cardKey2 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank2 = deckDictionary[cardKey2]?.first

        var cardKey3 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank3 = deckDictionary[cardKey3]?.first

        var cardKey4 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank4 = deckDictionary[cardKey4]?.first

        var cardKey5 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank5 = deckDictionary[cardKey5]?.first

        var cardKey6 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank6 = deckDictionary[cardKey6]?.first

        var cardKey7 = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
        var cardRank7 = deckDictionary[cardKey7]?.first

        var winRankArray = [cardRank1, cardRank2, cardRank3, cardRank4, cardRank5, cardRank6, cardRank7]

        //func sameRank {loop through winRankArray, find 3 identical values, set winRankStatus to true}
        let didWinRank = winRankArray.slidingWindowWithLength(4).contains{ $0.allEqual() }
```

Comment: What is `slidingWindowWithLength` return?

Comment: Try `deckDictionary[cardKey1]!.first` and same for all.

Comment: What @DharmeshKheni says, and add the appropriate nil checks. Also the `first` property you are calling returns an optional. So that will also return a `String?`

Answer (score 0):

> Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

I don't think so ...

```
var s1: String? = "alfa"
var s2: String? = nil
var s3: String? = "beta"
var arr: Array<String?> = [s1, s2, s3]
arr.contains { (str) -> Bool in  // true
    str == "alfa"
}
s1 == "alfa" // true
s1 == s3     // false
s2 == nil    // true
```

> When adopting Equatable, only the == operator is required to be
>   implemented. The standard library provides an implementation for !=.